# ORACLE DB query - maximum stipend in faculty

Tags: sql, oracle

So, i have an task in uni to get max stipend in each faculty from a table with stipends.

Faculty table is:

```
ID_FACULTY FACULTY_NAME                   DEAN                 TELEPHON
---------- ------------------------------ -------------------- --------
        10 Informacijas tehnologiju       Vitols               63023095
        11 Lauksaimniecibas               Gaile                63022584
        12 Tehniska                       Dukulis              53020762
        13 Partikas tehnologijas          Sabovics             63021075
```

Money table is:

```
 ID_PAYOUT STUDENT_ID PAYOUT_DA    STIPEND COMPENSATION
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------
       100          1 24-SEP-20      45.25           15
       101          7 20-SEP-20     149.99            0
       102          3 18-SEP-20        100            0
       103         17 02-SEP-20      90.85           20
       104          9 03-SEP-20         85           20
       105         19 09-SEP-20      70.75            0
       106         25 15-SEP-20         55           15
       107         17 17-SEP-20     105.54            0
       108         15 22-SEP-20         94            0
       109         27 28-SEP-20        100           20
```

And the student table is:

```
ID_STUDENT SURNAME                   NAME                 COURSE_YEAR FACULTY_ID BIRTHDATE
---------- ------------------------- -------------------- ----------- ---------- ---------
         1 Lapa                      Juris                          4         13 27-SEP-96
         3 Vilkauss                  Fredis                         2         10 17-MAY-99
         5 Karlsone                  Rasa                           1         11 13-MAR-00
         7 Grozitis                  Guntars                        3         12 16-APR-97
         9 Sonciks                   Jurgis                         2         10 17-MAR-99
        11 Berzajs                   Olafs                          3         10 14-FEB-97
        13 Vike                      Ilvija                         2         13 14-MAY-99
        15 Baure                     Inga                           3         11 12-APR-97
        17 Viskers                   Zigmunds                       2         13 15-AUG-99
        19 Talmanis                  Harijs                         3         13 15-JUL-97
        21 Livmanis                  Indulis                        1         10 19-JAN-00
        23 Shaveja                   Uva                            2         13 18-FEB-98
        25 Lacis                     Guntis                         4         10 17-SEP-96
        27 Liepa                     Guna                           4         11 18-AUG-96
        29 Klava                     Juris                          2         10 19-MAY-98
```

I have tried many variations of queries, i think that I even tried all the possible combinations of joins, but i cannot achieve the neccessary result.

One of my queries looked like this:

```
SQL> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY surname) "Nr.",
f.faculty_name,
s.surname,
s.name,
MAX(m.stipend)
FROM faculty f, student s INNER JOIN money m ON s.id_student = m.student_id
WHERE s.faculty_id = f.id_faculty
GROUP BY f.faculty_name, s.surname, s.name 
ORDER BY s.surname;
```

Which returned me the following result:

```
       Nr. FACULTY_NAME                   SURNAME                   NAME                 MAX(M.STIPEND)
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------- -------------------- --------------
         1 Lauksaimniecibas               Baure                     Inga                             94
         2 Tehniska                       Grozitis                  Guntars                      149.99
         3 Informacijas tehnologiju       Lacis                     Guntis                           55
         4 Partikas tehnologijas          Lapa                      Juris                         45.25
         5 Lauksaimniecibas               Liepa                     Guna                            100
         6 Informacijas tehnologiju       Sonciks                   Jurgis                           85
         7 Partikas tehnologijas          Talmanis                  Harijs                        70.75
         8 Informacijas tehnologiju       Vilkauss                  Fredis                          100
         9 Partikas tehnologijas          Viskers                   Zigmunds                     105.54

9 rows selected.
```

So the goal of this task is to retrieve the maximum amount of stipend granted to a student in a certain faculty.
Can someone please tell what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And give the student details as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just max amount per faculty:

```
SELECT 
f.faculty_name,
MAX(m.stipend)
FROM    
   faculty f
   INNER JOIN student s ON s.faculty_id = f.id_faculty 
   INNER JOIN money m ON s.id_student = m.student_id
GROUP BY f.faculty_name
```

Max amount and all other details too:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.faculty_name ORDER BY m.stipend desc) rn,
   f.*,
   s.*,
   m.*
 FROM  
   faculty f
   INNER JOIN student s ON s.faculty_id = f.id_faculty 
   INNER JOIN money m ON s.id_student = m.student_id
) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Points of note:

- Do not use old style joins; if you ever write one `table_name, other_table_name` in a FROM block, you're using old style joins. Don't do it; they became bad news about 30 years ago
- When you have a max-n-per-group, you specify how finely detailed the group is. If you `GROUP BY s.first_name, s.last_name, f.faculty_name` then your groups are "every unique combination of firstname/lastname/faculty, so the only way you'll get multiple items in your group is if there are two John Smiths in Mathematics. If the group is to be the whole of mathematics, then the faculty name (and anything else that is uniquely related 1:1 to it, like the faculty ID) is all that you can put in your group. Anything not in a group must be in an aggregation, like MAX
- When you want other details too, you either group and max the data and then join this groupmaxed data back to the original data to use it as a filter, or you use an approach like here where you use a row_number or rank, with a partition (which is like an autojoined grouped summary). There is no group here; the row numbering acts like a group because it restarts from 1 every different faculty and proceeds incrementally as stipend decreses. This means that the highest stipend is always in row number 1.
- Unlike using a groupmax that you join back to get the detail, the row_number route does not produce duplicate rows with tied-for-highest stipends

Comment: Is there a way so the row numbers are like 1,2,3,4? I know, that those are some begginer questions, but that is who I am right now in Oracle DB and in DB systems overall.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; You can number the rows again with another rownumber if you like; the rownumber you see in the second query is used to calculate the max via `where rn = 1`, so you can't use it to be 2,3,4 ...

Comment: I wanted to say, that I am curious, how to make the rownum a sequence of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) instead of being constant number defined with that where rn = 1

Comment: Make it `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...), x.* FROM ...`